# ReactiveVar not defined

Tags: variables, meteor

https://jsfiddle.net/o78fjwbq/2/

```
var feckinHell = new ReactiveVar(0);
if (feckinHell.get() > 0) { make reservation() };
```

Im iterating over data and reactiveVar would be defined in helper comparing query against database for reservation which would be used to determine if reservation may be made against room type. I tried return reactiveVar.get.set pattern, but thats obviusly not working.

Uncought reference error: feckinHell is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using meteor 1.3 then you first have to import it. like this

```
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var'
```

And If you are using less version then make sure you have install the reactive var package because its not a pre-installed package.

Comment: Yea it's imported, and installed and 1.3V. I imported it in the rooms which is where i use it rather than roomslist.

Comment: I am not gettting but you have to import reactive var in every js where you want to user reative var. something like this .....


import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var'
var feckinHell = new ReactiveVar(0);
if (feckinHell.get() > 0) { make reservation() };

Comment: yes it's what I have still undefined in "feckingHell.set(this.amount-x)" in counter function.

Comment: I had to run "meteor add reactive-var" in my project directory

Comment: Yes, or you can directly add in meteor package file.